# Firebase - quickest way to update node value with node value + value

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm looking for Firebase equivalent to

`UPDATE users SET credits = credits + 10`

I want to update specific value in my firebase database without loading all of the data. The following example will not work but just illustrating what I mean:

```
    let user = this.af.database.object('/user/').update({
          count1: count1 + 50
          count2: count2 + 20
        });
```

Is there any way to add value to an existing data without loading it?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, no, you need to use `transaction` for adding or subtracting.

See here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#transaction